# Use of <%= %> instead of <% %> ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been following Agile Web Development with Rails, and their code suddenly switches from the use of `<%= %>` to `<% %>`.

Code Example 1:

```
<%= 1+2 %>
```

Code Example 2:

```
<% for file in @files %>    
file name is: <%= file %>
<% end %>
```

My question is, for the second code sample why can I not use `<%= %>`?

Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Common question, hard to search for. Bound to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ERB (embedded ruby) syntax, `<%= %>` is shorthand for "perform the following ruby code AND THEN print the result". So in the first example, it will print the result of the operation 1 + 2, 3.

The second example shows a for loop which will iterate and print the contents between the `for` declaration and its corresponding `<% end %>`.

To answer your question, the expression `for file in @files` itself doesn't return anything worth printing so there's no need to use `<%= %>` and in fact doing so can cause a hard-to-track-down bug.

Comment: Best way to think about it is `<%=` is the equivalent of `echo` in PHP. So `<%=` == `<$ echo`